# Doing a Select query syntax from a Dataset table with Sum() and Group by clause

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Is there a way to query a dataset table?

I was trying to apply this to the dataset table but I do not the syntax

```
SELECT [In], F2, [Out], F5, SUM(Hours) 
FROM Table1
WHERE (F2 = (SELECT TOP 1 FROM Table1 ORDER BY ASC)
  AND F5 = (SELECT TOP 1 FROM Table1 ORDER BY DESC))
GROUP BY IN, OUT;
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this syntax is wrong. `SELECT TOP 1 FROM`. You need to select a column at least. If you show sample data and expected results that would increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Hi sorry for lacking info, what I'm trying is how I can implement this select statement to a Dataset table in c#. I know its of different syntax but if there's a way to code this in this structure. I am going to put the data from the result to a new dataset table.

Comment: You want this SQL code to execute in your C# app right?

Comment: Show us the columns in Table1. Do you know how to use SQL? What is F2 and F5?

Comment: You can't. but you can use linq.